# Need a hinge that pushes outwards as the door opens

Tags: woodworking, wooden-furniture, hinges, custom-cabinetry

I'm fitting doors to a wardrobe frame I've built. The wardrobe frame is MDF with a 2x1 frame, fitted into a corner of a (wonky) room in our (old) house.

When the wardrobe door is closed I want it to fit flush to the frame, lined up with no overlap either way. However the hinges I have only give maybe a centimetre of 'push out', so the door would have to be smaller than the frame.

What sort of hinge do I need to source that will push the door outwards as it opens, by at least 4.5cm (which is the width of the 2x1 framing timber)? Been googling but it hasn't availed me of much.

Alternatively if anyone has any alternative suggestions, please fire away. I've thought of cutting a slot out of the 2x1 framing, to allow the hinge to attach closer to the edge of the door panel and thus get closer to what I want, but I'd prefer to avoid it looking untidy inside.

Also considering an externally mounted hinge that attaches to the outside edge of the side frame and the front of the door, maybe a wrought iron one to look nice.

PFA a top-down sketch to illustrate my ideal outcome. Door, when open, could frankly end up anywhere, it's the flush-when-closed result that matters most.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is as close as you are going to get, because of the width of your face-frame:

[image]

Comment: There are all kinds of special-application hinges out there. Some manufacturers help out with various design tools and such, like these guys: https://www.blum.com/us/en/

Comment: That looks pretty close to what I'm after, thanks.

Comment: Many home stores have many of these cabinet hinges with displays set up so you can actually operate them to see exactly how they'll work. +

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure that Blum sells what you want (or at least they did, about 20 years ago).

Comment: Thanks all. Browsing a shop not so easy at the moment, alas. ;-) I can google based on this, though.